# ionic 2 REST API : Failed to load url

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, cordova-2.0.0

I have the error while running the command ionic serve. I am trying to call the api using post method.

I got the error:

> Failed to load http://abc.localhost/api/auth/login: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8101' is therefore not allowed access.

How can I overcome on this?

I have written the api's in YII2 framework in api module with below behaviour:

```
 public function behaviors() {
     $behaviors = parent::behaviors();
     $behaviors['contentNegotiator'] = [
         'class' => 'yii\filters\ContentNegotiator',
         'formats' => [
             'text/html' => Response::FORMAT_JSON,
             'application/json' => Response::FORMAT_JSON,
             'application/xml' => Response::FORMAT_XML,
         ],
     ];
     $behaviors['corsFilter'] = [
         'class' => \yii\filters\Cors::className(),
         'cors' => [
             'Origin' => ['*'],
             'Access-Control-Request-Method' => ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'PATCH', 'DELETE', 'HEAD', 'OPTIONS'],
             'Access-Control-Request-Headers' => ['*'],
             'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' => true,
             'Access-Control-Max-Age' => 86400,
             'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' => ['*', 'http://abc.localhost/*', 'http://localhost:8101/*']
         ],
     ];
     return $behaviors; }
```

And my ionic2 cordova api call script is:

```
loading.present();
console.log(this.singleton.apiGuestToken);
let headers = new Headers();
headers.append("Accept", 'application/json');
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
headers.append('Authorization', this.singleton.apiGuestToken);
headers.append('withCredentials', 'true');
headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://abc.localhost');

let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
console.log(options);
let paramsData = { 'userType': userType, 'email': this.email, 'password': this.password };
console.log(paramsData);
this.http.post('http://abc.localhost/api/auth/login', paramsData, options)
  .map(res => res.json()) //this.singleton.apiUrl +
  .subscribe(data => {
    let resultData = JSON.parse(data['_body']);
    console.log(resultData);
       }, error => {
    console.log(error);// Error getting the data
    loading.dismiss();
  });
```

Even, I can't see the post parameters and Authentication in the chrome inspect.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I wonder lots of for this issue but I found a simple solution [here](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-cli/issues/213)

I added below code into ionic.confog.json

```
{
  "name": "MyApp",
  "app_id": "",
  "integrations": {
    "cordova": {}
  },
  "proxies": [
    {
      "path": "/api",
      "proxyUrl" : "http://abc.localhost/api/"
    }
  ],
  "type": "ionic-angular"
}
```

Now I am calling the rest api from the action `http://abc.localhost/api/auth/login` using POST method.

Previously I was trying using:

```
this.http.post('http://abc.localhost/api/auth/login', paramsData, options)
.subscribe(data => {
    let resultData = JSON.parse(data['_body']);
    console.log(resultData);
       }, error => {
    console.log(error);// Error getting the data
    loading.dismiss();
  });
```

But I was needed to call api like this:

```
this.http.post('api/auth/login', paramsData, options)
.subscribe(data => {
    let resultData = JSON.parse(data['_body']);
    console.log(resultData);
       }, error => {
    console.log(error);// Error getting the data
    loading.dismiss();
  });
```

See the difference is calling rest api URL as proxies path was already been set in config file. 
This works for me.

Answer (score 1):

During development you can use [**CORS** plugin **for Google Chrome**](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en).

> CORS is only an issue when we are running or testing our app when
>   running `ionic serve` or `ionic run -l`.
>
> There are two ways to solve the issue: The first, and easier, solution
>   is to just allow all origins from your API endpoint. However, we can’t
>   always control the endpoint we are accessing. What we need, then, is a
>   request that does not specify an `origin`. - [**Handling CORS issues in Ionic**](http://blog.ionic.io/handling-cors-issues-in-ionic/)

Comment: Thank you for the answer Tomislav! I tried to run command `ionic cordova run -l` to run app on device. It shows me **Failed to load http://abc.localhost/api/auth/login: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8100' is therefore not allowed access.**